# Copy and paste key mapping in Neovim Lua configuration

Tags: lua, neovim

I just started replacing my Vim configuration file with the equivalent Lua version. Within the Lua version, I'm trying to make a simple copy/paste to clipboard key mapping so that I can select text with `v` and then click `Ctrl`+`c` and `Ctrl`+`v` to copy and paste.

I figured that I need to map `"+y` and `"+p`, so I tried the following:

```lua
local keymap = vim.api.nvim_set_keymap
keymap("n", "<C-c>", '"+y', opts)
keymap("n", "<C-v>", '<ESC>"+pa', opts)
```

However, this doesn't work. Any ideas on how I can get the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap("n", "<c-c>", '"*y :let @+=@*<CR>', {noremap=true, silent=true})
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap("n", "<c-v>", '"+p', {noremap=true, silent=true})
```

Add i,v,x... to that first quotes for other modes.

I see you're doing some extra things like escape and appending, so maybe it isn't all the way there for your workflow - but this should get you going.

Answer (score 1):

I have a map helper function:

```lua
-- ~/.config/nvim/lua/mappings.lua
-- in your init.lua use: require('mappings')
local function map(mode, lhs, rhs, opts)
    local options = { noremap = true }
    if opts then
        options = vim.tbl_extend("force", options, opts)
    end
    vim.api.nvim_set_keymap(mode, lhs, rhs, options)
end
```

By default **options** are used, just in case you use any option these are merged with options.

Now you can create mappings like this:

```
-- Update Plugins
map("n", "<Leader>u", ":PackerSync<CR>")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest retaining/making use of the default "paste from the system clipboard" keyboard shortcut `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`v` which works inside of many (if not all) terminals and terminal-based applications—this has two main benefits<sup>†</sup>:

1. You retain the default keyboard mapping for Neovim's visual block selection mode.
2. It trains muscle memory for a shortcut that works almost universally in terminal environments (resulting in fewer mental checks prior to action(s), which leads to faster, semi-autonomous output).

Assuming you concur with the above, the following mappings can be used to handle copying and cutting in both normal and visual modes within Neovim with `Ctrl`+`c` and `Ctrl`+`v`, respectively:

```lua
-- Copying to system clipboard
-- From current cursor position to EOL (normal mode)
vim.keymap.set({'n'}, '<C-c>', '"+y$')
-- Current selection (visual mode)
vim.keymap.set({'v'}, '<C-c>', '"+y')

-- Cutting to system clipboard
-- From current cursor position to EOL (normal mode)
vim.keymap.set({'n'}, '<C-x>', '"+d$')
-- Current selection (visual mode)
vim.keymap.set({'v'}, '<C-x>', '"+d')

-- For info. on why vim.keymap.set() is preferred over vim.api.nvim_set_keymap(), 
-- see https://github.com/neovim/neovim/commit/6d41f65aa45f10a93ad476db01413abaac21f27d
```

Now whenever you use `Ctrl`+`c`, `Ctrl`+`x` and `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`v` you know you're always interacting with the system clipboard. I find the copy/cut from current cursor position to the End Of Line (EOL) mappings very useful as it complements the traditional selection-based copy/cut mappings well.

---

<sup>†</sup> I understand that the same logic could be used to justify using the default `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`c` command for copying as well. However, unlike `Ctrl`+`v`, `Ctrl`+`c` and `Ctrl`+`x` aren't mapped to anything useful by default, and, further to point 2 above, using them as copy/cut is tapping into muscle memory that already exists for most people.